# Add 5 images to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have 5 images that I wish to put into a UIScrollView, so that the user can scroll between them.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can google "UIScrollView tutorial", for example.

Answer (score 2):

You're better off using `UICollectionView` and have each image in it's own cell. Then all of the `contentSize`, positioning and scrolling nonsense is handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `UICollectionView` but if you insist on using a `UIScrollView` you can do something like the following:

.h file

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scv;

@end
```

.m

```
@interface MyViewController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imageArray;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize scv = _scv, imageArray = _imageArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [_arrayOfImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"]]; // Do this for as many UIImages you want to add.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)configureView
{
    _scv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    float yposition = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < [_arrayOfImages count]; i++) {
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yposition, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 100)];
        [img setImage:[_arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:i];
        [img setTag:i];
        [_scv addSubview:img];
        yposition =+ 100 + 10; // get the current yposition = yposition + img height + an extra 10 to add a gap.
    }    
    [_scv setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.height, yposition)]; // Set the width to match the screen size, and set the height as the final yposition.
    [[self view] addSubview:_scv];
}

@end
```

This is a very simple version of what you're after there are more complex version that will allow for easier implementation of `Add New Image`, `Remove Image` etc

If you have any more questions are want to know how to implement new features just ask.